# How to transfer normal.dot on Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2003

I had to reinstall Vista and all of my programs and I want to know how to copy my normal.dot that I have saved on a flash drive into the word 2003 program.

Answer (score 1):

The file is located at Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates where Username is the account name you used to log in.

According to this Microsoft [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826839) the template is created the first time you run Word. So there won't be a file in this location until you run Word once.

I use Windows XP, so the following instructions might be off by a bit, but I think they will work.

- open Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer) by holding down the Windows key and pressing E.
- Navigate to c:\Documents and Settings
- You should see a number of folders with people's names (account names) on them. One will have the name of your account on it. This is often your name or nickname (it depends what you called the account when you installed Windows). Select this folder.
- This will contain a folder called Application Data. Select this folder.
- This will contain a folder called Microsoft. Select this folder.
- This will contain a folder called Templates. Select this folder.
- Drag the Normal.dot file from the flash drive to this folder.

Comment: Actually, I am a dunce.  I have no clue how to do that.  I have been trying to drag normal from my flash drive to normal in my work program, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yay!! It worked.  Thank you so very much!!  I sure do appreciate your help.  I have been very stressed out about all of this.  Thanks again!!